# BigQuery Case Statement for Datetime doesn't work for Null values

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm writing a simple case statement in BigQuery to check the value of a Datetime:

```
select
case datetime_field
when null then 'Open'
else 'Closed'
end
from a_table
```

There are null values in the datetime_field yet the case statement evaluates to 'Else'.

The following simple select statement does return the values:

```
select * from a_table where datetime_field is null
```

Any idea why then a Case statement doesn't evaluate null datetime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/conditional_expressions#case_expr):

> Compares expr to expr_to_match of each successive WHEN clause and returns the first result where this comparison returns true. The remaining WHEN clauses and else_result are not evaluated. If the expr = expr_to_match comparison returns false or NULL for all WHEN clauses, returns else_result if present; if not present, returns NULL.

and the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/operators)

> Unless otherwise specified, all operators return NULL when one of the operands is NULL.

So, when null is used in the case when, it means the `datetime_field = null` is evaluated and the result return NULL. The else claused is evaluated and return "Closed".

To fix this, use the `IF` function instead:

```
select if(datetime_field is null, "Open", "Closed") from a_table
```